# How can I get around a slurpy parameter in the Perl 6 signature?

Tags: signature, raku

I have this short example where I want to take out two elements of an Array and replace it with a single element that's an array:

```
my @digits  = <1 2 3>.map: { [ $_, $_ ] };
say @digits;  # [[1 1] [2 2] [3 3]]

@digits.splice: 0, 2, [4,4];
say @digits; # [4 4 [3 3]]
```

This doesn't work because the [splice](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Array#routine_splice) replacement is actually the slurpy `*@replacement`, so it flattens it all.

I could try to itemize it so it's treated as a single thing, but that is still flattened:

```
@digits.splice: 0, 2, $[4,4];
say @digits;
```

I can put that item in another array and I get what I want, but this seems too much work (especially since I'd like to decide if it's flattened or not):

```
@digits.splice: 0, 2, [$[4,4]];
say @digits; # [[4 4] [3 3]]
```

Is there a better way to work around this?

Comment: Have you tried `**@…` or `+@…`?

Comment: I think the loss of containerization is actually a bug.  I've reported it as such as https://rt.perl.org/rt3/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=131162.  Any fix won't make it in this months release though, as there may actually be some ecosystem fallout as this bug has been around at least since 2015.12.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `([4,4],)` (as alternative for  `[$[4,4]]`

```
@digits.splice: 0, 2, ([4,4],); #or [[4,4],];
```

or more replacements

```
@digits.splice: 0, 2, [4,4], Empty; #or ,slip();
```